# Simple way to make group of alphabet and numbers from a given string

Tags: java, string

I need to make groups of numbers and single alphabet from a given string, like:

> 15D12A3C11B12A

into

> 15D, 12A, 3C, 11B, 12A

and store the **output** individually in **separate variables**

There's only one alphabet between any two given numbers except in the end of the string and string always begins with a number. Alphabets can be A-Z, uppercase only.

Comment: I suggest you to make clear your question starting with:"What is alphabet for you?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use a `Matcher`:

```
String str = "15D12A3C11B12A";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
15D
12A
3C
11B
12A
```

Comment: One of the best approach. +1 for that

Comment: Damn, you were a little faster ;-)

Comment: I understood the answer but not question :)

Comment: This would also match strings like "15?12A3C11B12!". If only characters from A-Z should be matched, the pattern should be changed to "\\d+[A-Z]" or "\\d+[a-zA-Z]"

Comment: How to store the output individually in separate variables?

Comment: Read the documentation. `m.find()` searches the string for the first occurence, `m.group()` then returns the result of that search. So obviously, you just do `m.find(); someVar = m.group();`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints out the matches vertically. You just need to adjust it to get the desired result string. The regex means: 1..n digits followed by exactly one character from A-Z. If you want to support lower case characters, adjust it to `\\d+[a-zA-Z]`

```
String str = "15D12A3C11B12A";
String pattern = "\\d+[A-Z]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: should be `"\\d+[A-Z]"`

Comment: Depends on the requirement, but in this particular case you're right. I'll edit the answer